# Introduction to Analysis: L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

For class, we are to prove L'Hospital's Rule for $\infty/\infty$ case,

Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$; choose a so that $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\approx_{\epsilon}L$ for $x>a$.

Prove the two approximations below (valid for $x$>>$1$)

$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\approx_{\epsilon}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\approx_{\epsilon}L.$

Hints given to us for the first approximation, was $f(x)-f(a)=f(x)[1-f(a)/f(x)]$ and use limit theorem. For the second approximation, use the Cauchy Mean-value Theorem.

I have an idea, but I do not know how to continue from here. This is what I have for the first approximation.

For any $\epsilon$, choose $x_0$ sufficiently large such that $1-\epsilon<\frac{1-f(a)/f(x)}{1-g(a)/g(x)}<1+\epsilon$, whenever $x>x_0$.

For the second one: by the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c, a<c<x$ such that $(f(x)-f(a))g'(c)=(g(x)-g(a))f'(c)$, that is: $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$ which is $\epsilon$-close to $L. $

This is where I am stuck. How would we continue to pursue the proof from here?

Answer (score 1):

Since your text suggests using limit theorems for the first, let's do that. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f(a)}{f(x)} = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{g(a)}{g(x)} = 0$, we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\,,$$
and so you can rewrite this with your $\approx_\epsilon$ notation for $x>b$.

The second approximation is valid because $c>a$ and you've assumed $\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\approx_\epsilon L$ for $x>a$.

Putting together your two estimates you obtain $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\approx_{2\epsilon} L$ for $x>b>a$.